# iOS Interface Builder: How to make templates

Tags: ios, xcode, view, interface-builder, subclass

I've recently started developing an iOS app, which I've never done before, so it's been going a bit slow, but I'm learning, so that's understandable.

I want to make a custom interface, so I've been making subclasses of the default view classes (like UIButton) so that I can define custom drawing. I've been told this is the best way to define custom interface elements that can be reusable. It definitely seems to be working that way. However, I haven't been able to make elements completely reusable by just using a subclass.

For example, in order to prevent a button's text from changing color when it is clicked, I have to manually go into the interface builder and set the button type to "Custom." After that, code that I enter into the subclass's constructor to change attributes seems to work. But I have to do this for every button I add, and in code the "buttonType" attribute is read only. Is there a way for me to define (just once) certain attributes for every instance of my button subclass that I add to the interface?

My goal is to be able to have a button subclass or template that defines all attribute values that I want my buttons to have, and every instance that I add automatically reflects those properties without me having to change anything. More so, I want to be able to modify that subclass/template and have those changes reflected in every existing instance. I have to imagine that this is possible in iOS. There is simply no way to build sophisticated interfaces without this capability.

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom Button class (inherited from UIButton) in your project and in the `init` set the properties which you wanted to be set across.

In the interface builder go to the the class inspector and enter the button to be of the previously declared button.

`buttonType` needs to be set for all the button as this is defined at initialization time and exposed as read only property. If you want absolute reusability for your case, create a view, with an embedded button in code. when you create a button, create using the static method `buttonWithType`.

Wherever you need, drag and drop a UIView and set the view type to be the custom view.

Comment: Now that I've been using this a little more, I realize that a subclass is really all I need. However, the fact that I have to set buttons to "Custom" to get my custom attributes to work is confusing. I feel like I should be able to define all behaviors and attributes in both code and the interface builder.